# HTML Form / Input Autocomplete off

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, autocomplete

Autocomplete has been causing me trouble for quite some time. It overlays buttons and search results which causes users to click it instead of a link on the webpage.

I have been searching the internet for solutions to this for literally years. None of them are both practical and work consistently. I have tried all the alternatives to "off" listed throughout the relevant Google searches.

Below I have uploaded a GIF. The GIF shows me triggering autocomplete on an input which has autocomplete set to off.

I then remove the name attribute of a separate input within the form and suddenly autocomplete switches off.

I also demonstrate that having the keyword "Company" in the placeholder seems to override autocomplete=off. However, this does not seem to override autocomplete=off in all situations.

In the below example I used a datepicker, but I can also reproduced the problem with simple text inputs.

Is there a reason behind this strange behavior?

One solution is to use type="search", however, this may not be the desired approach for all developers.

Thanks in advance.

[image: autocomplete fail]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
<input name="unm" id="unm" type="text" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
```

Comment: Yes, does not work. Also, if it did work, it would only work for the first click. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a form method.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
    <label for="cc">Please work:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" placeholder="Enter a company here" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found the form attributes have no effect. :(

Comment: you have a form too, try to put inside your form  autocomplete="off" attribute (<form class="quoter" autocomplete="off" .... >

Comment: Hi copyka22, I have updated the original post to highlight the current working solution. I found the solution by looking at how websites like Google, Facebook and Reddit solve the problem. type = "search". There is currently no consistent solution for any other type of input.